# Documentation / guides for offline ubuntu phone scopes

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, phone, offline, scopes

I've been working on an Ubuntu phone scope that is NOT connecting to the internet, it is retrieving local results.

I am having difficulty, which is mostly due to not having a guide for how to write a scope for offline use. The tutorials are all for online scopes, and even the Ubuntu SDK setup wizards for scopes are all for online. Is there anything I can work with currently? I know it's early still in the development for Ubuntu on a phone.

Thanks,
Randy

Comment: Is there particular local data you want access to from your scope?  As it stands, this is quite a broad question and difficult to answer.

Comment: Well the questions is: is there any documentation to write a scope that is NOT connecting to the internet. If that doesn’t exist yet, then yes, I have some c++ functions that return some numbers and text (from polling local system). Example: hard drive size.

Comment: If you don't make any network calls in your scope, then it isn't connecting to the internet.  If you want to use local data, generate your results from the local data instead.

Comment: The default apparmor file uses the "ubuntu-scope-network" profile.  If I'm reading the docs correctly, this prohibits all local file access.  ("If you need to use the network at some point, you won’t be able to access user data.")  What template should be used instead for a scope not connecting to the internet?

Comment: @RobertSchroll I think it is `ubuntu-scope-local` for the profile. But you can't use network with that, and you still can't access everything on the device. Local file access is still quite limited.